# Fetching value from particular cell using jquery

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

note : firstly i select the row and below code will be used to fetch id

var allocationid = $(this).parents("tr").children("td").eq(0).text();

my jquery code .. using eq .

but i dont want to use eq . i want in dynamic way. fetch with the help of column name

//table format
table has thead and tbody tag

```
<table>
<thead>
      <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>name</th>
      </tr><br>
<thead>
<tbody>
     <tr>
     <td>01</td>
     <td>joe</td>
     </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

```
let colName_NPDId = 'NPDId';
    let index1 = $(this).closest("table").find(`thead tr th:contains(${colName_NPDId})`).index();
    let npdid = $(this).closest("tr").children("td").eq(index1).text();
```

this code I Used (reference of this comment) but this code fetch value of hidden column only(jqgrid). please help me out

Comment: But what would be the "Dynamic way" for you? Would it be for example `$(this).parents("tr").children("td").eq("ID").text();`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the index of the column name from the header, then use that in `.eq()`.

```
let colName = 'ID';
let index = $(this).closest("table").find(`thead tr th:contains(${colName})`).index();
let allocationId = $(this).closest("tr").children("td").eq(index).text();
```

Explanation:

- `$(this).closest("table")` gets the enclosing table.
- `.find(`thead tr th:contains(${colName})`)` finds the heading cell containing the column name we care about.
- `.index()` returns its position in the row.
- `$(this).closest("tr")` gets the current row.
- `.children("td")` returns all the `<td>` elements in the current row
- `.eq(index)` returns the element with the same index we determined above
- `.text()` returns its text content.

Comment: Thankyou So much .  
got Solution . 

please explain whats going on ur code .  explain please.

Comment: @BabaRanjith I added more details, does this clarify?

Comment: tq so much for clearing my doubt.

Comment: =================================
let colName_FGCode = 'FGCode';
    let index2 = $(this).closest("table").find(`thead tr th:contains(${colName_FGCode})`).index();
    let fgcode = $(this).closest("tr").children("td").eq(index2 ).text();
=============

hello @Barmar . whichever column name i take , still take value of same column (-1 )

=====================================
let fgcode = $(this).closest("tr").children("td").eq(1).text(); 
=====================================
right now am using like this please help me out

Comment: Can you upate the question with sample code demonstrating the problem? Use [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).